# Visual Studio Code Python extension: None of the default / built-in modules working (pylint, autopep8, etc)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It's my understanding that the Python extension's built-in features, e.g., linting with pylint should work with the default user / global settings, and if an alternative linter is preferred, insertion of a full path to the executable is required.

In my case, none of the features are working, all emitting 'not installed' error messages, even after using the command palette and responding in the affirmative to the error dialog when asked '... install?'

Developer Tools > Console reveals:
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -c "import pylint" ... 
... 'pylint' not installed.

at f.execModule (c:\Users\Moron.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\out\client\extension.js:9:41305)
at async d.run (c:\Users\Moron.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\out\client\extension.js:1:210891)
at async d.runLinter (c:\Users\Moron.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\out\client\extension.js:75:1367669)]

and the same for autopep8, and down the line.

Is it necessary to enter full paths to each of the default features' executables in the various settings (global, user, workspace) prior to using them? I've not seen any tutorials that mention this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally installed tools are **not** used by default, but instead tools installed that can be executed using Python's `-m` argument. If you would like to use globally-installed tools then you will need to specify them in your settings, e.g. `"python.linting.pylintPath"`. But your best option is to create a virtual environment and install the tools there.

Comment: This is helpful information indeed, Brett. I got rather lost in my journey to track down all the different file / folder locations that VSCode was making use of, and certainly lost sight of the forest for the trees. Thanks a lot.